# Wifi 7265AC is not connected in ubuntu 17.10

Tags: networking, wireless, 17.10, bluetooth, intel

The 7265AC wifi module does not connect in Ubuntu 17.10. I've updated the drivers, but it's still not connected, neither bluetooth. Why?

### some outputs:

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7265 [8086:095a] (rev 59)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7265 [8086:5010]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

---

```
$ rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

---

```
$ iwconfig
wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=0 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp1s0    no wireless extensions.
```

---

```
$ dmesg | grep iwl
[    3.736393] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: enabling device (0100 -> 0102)
[    3.743942] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 29.610311.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    3.765152] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7265, REV=0x210
[    3.783239] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: base HW address: e4:42:a6:3b:0c:8b
[    3.851759] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[    3.955842] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
```

---

```
$ ifconfig -a
enp1s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.110  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::f2ae:7543:fb54:a383  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 3c:52:82:99:88:9e  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 80948  bytes 110611689 (110.6 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 42284  bytes 4334915 (4.3 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Loopback Local)
        RX packets 1920  bytes 177354 (177.3 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1920  bytes 177354 (177.3 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp2s0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether e4:42:a6:3b:0c:8b  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

---

```
$ sudo lshw -c network
  *-network                 
       descrição: Ethernet interface
       produto: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       fabricante: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       ID físico: 0
       informações do barramento: pci@0000:01:00.0
       nome lógico: enp1s0
       versão: 15
       serial: 3c:52:82:99:88:9e
       tamanho: 1Gbit/s
       capacidade: 1Gbit/s
       largura: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capacidades: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuração: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=192.168.1.110 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
       recursos: irq:128 porta de E/S:3000(tamanho=256) memória:e0204000-e0204fff memória:e0200000-e0203fff
  *-network
       descrição: Interface sem fio
       produto: Wireless 7265
       fabricante: Intel Corporation
       ID físico: 0
       informações do barramento: pci@0000:02:00.0
       nome lógico: wlp2s0
       versão: 59
       serial: e4:42:a6:3b:0c:8b
       largura: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capacidades: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuração: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.13.0-37-generic firmware=29.610311.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       recursos: irq:134 memória:e0100000-e0101fff
```

Answer (score 0):

I would turn off wifi power management and see if we can get some tx power from the card, in terminal

```
sudo sed -i 's/wifi.powersave = 3/wifi.powersave = 2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf
sudo iwconfig wlp2s0 txpower 20
systemctl restart network-manager.service
```

Then see if you can connect

Comment: Thanks. But it's not working yet... The only change was the `Power Management:off` in the iwconfig output.

Comment: Try `sudo iwconfig wlp2s0 txpower 18` and see if that changes the tx power

Comment: Thanks. I am wondering the problem is that I don't have any antenna connected to the wifi module. I will buy someone to try connect it.